# Interrupting an looping function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trigger the following function when a tooltip is clicked. It is an ajax poll.

There can be many tooltips on the page, and more than one can need access to the data retrieved from the server.

What I want to achieve is to have this poll running as one instance - so if the user clicks a different tooltip the polling stops, rather than being duplicated.

Would be grateful if you could help.

Thanks

```
function doConversationsAjaxLongPoll(tablename){

clientSubmit = new Object;

// HERE WE'RE GOING TO GET A LIST OF THE ROWIDS THAT WE NEED TO POLL FOR, MAKE AN OBJECT OUT OF THEM. DO THIS BY LOOKING AT WHICH //TOOLIPS HAVE CLASS OPEN
var tooltips = [];
$('.tooltipOpen').each(function(index){
    tooltips.push($(this).data('idrow'))
})

console.log("tooltips length: " + tooltips.length)
    if(tooltips.length==0){
//      console.log("tooltip length is 0 so we're returning false")
        return false
    }

clientSubmit.OpenConversations = tooltips
clientSubmit.tablename = tablename
clientSubmit.CurrentData = $('body').data('conversations')

console.log(clientSubmit)

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/conversations.php?loadNew=1',
  data: clientSubmit,
  timeout: 25000,
    success: function(data){
      console.log('success')
      data=JSON.parse(data)
      console.log(data)
      $('body').data('conversations', data)

    },
    complete: function(status, jqXHR){
    if(tooltips.length==0){
    //  console.log("tooltip length is 0 so we're returning false")
        return false
    }
    else
    {
      doConversationsAjaxLongPoll(tablename);
    }
    }
});
updateConversations()
}
```

Comment: var current;
    function setCurrent(newCurrent) {
      if (current && current != newCurrent) {
        current.cancel();
      }
      current = newCurrent;
      current.cancel = function() {
        // remove previous
      }
    }
    $("a").click(function (e) { setCurrent(e.target); })

Comment: I guess what I need is some idea of how to do the //remove previous bit...

Comment: Should I have the function as a method in an object and somehow invoke that method or something? Would really appreciate some help...

Answer (score 0):

I don't doubt that there are faaaar better ways of doing this but I have worked around the problem by having a random number generated by the click function, stored in $('body').data('random') which is then passed to the poll function. When the poll function loops it checks if the random number it was passed matches the one in data-random and returns false if it doesn't.